# Read pipe value from JSON based on Condition - Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-material

I have the following JSON:

```
columns: [{
    id: 'id',
    header: 'Employee ID',
    value: 'id',
    hasPipe: false
  },
  {
    id: 'name',
    header: 'Employee Name',
    value: 'name',
    hasPipe: true,
    pipe: 'customPipe'
  },
  {
    id: 'address',
    header: 'Employee address',
    value: 'address',
    hasPipe: false
  },
]
```

In the HTML file,
I have the following code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let eachCol of Columns" matColumnDef="{{eachCol.id}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{eachCol.header}}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        {{ eachCol.hasPipe ? (row[eachCol.value] | eachCol.pipe) : (row[eachCol.value]) }}
      </td>
</ng-container>
```

I have referred following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937308/7100922
I get template parse errors.

Comment: You are sure that error is cause because of the pipe?, what happen if you test like without the pipe? something like this `{{ eachCol.hasPipe ? (row[eachCol.value] + ' | ' + eachCol.pipe) : (row[eachCol.value]) }}`.

Comment: You cannot use a dynamic pipe like that. I suppose you can use a master pipe and pass in the pipe name through there, and choose from within that pipe which pipe should be used for the transform

Comment: I tried using dynamic pipe... have followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910713/7100922, now I'm getting StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[customPipe]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for customPipe!g  error. Have declared customPipe in the providers array.