# How to define a pipe from input?

Tags: angular

Currently I am writing a component, I want to give as input a pipe. I tried to use

```js
export class exampleComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input pipe;
}
```

```html
{{ text | pipe }}
```

but it is trying to get a pipe named 'pipe'. I want to use the pipe that it received from the input.

any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You cannot just pass something and use it as a pipe. Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564976/dynamic-pipe-in-angular-2) it may help you